# Activeadmin sortable by multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activeadmin

Is there any possibility to sort `activeadmin` table using multiple columns?

I've found an [issue](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/909) that says it is impossible now. But I wonder if anyone has implemented such functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've faced same issue. Judging by [source code](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/collection.rb#L43-L56) this feature isn't supported

```
    def sort_order(chain)
      params[:order] ||= active_admin_config.sort_order
      if params[:order] && params[:order] =~ /^([\w\_\.]+)_(desc|asc)$/
        column = $1
        order  = $2
        table  = active_admin_config.resource_table_name
        table_column = (column =~ /\./) ? column :
          "#{table}.#{active_admin_config.resource_quoted_column_name(column)}"

        chain.reorder("#{table_column} #{order}")
      else
        chain # just return the chain
      end
    end
```

But [there is](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1766#issuecomment-10450799) monkey patch solution.

Comment: Thanks, I achieved this in the same way

Comment: Hi., I need to implement this functionality(default sort with multiple columns) in my web app.

Where should i need to write the above method? and whats the syntax to include this in the default sort..? 

This is my current code:
ActiveAdmin.register Game, { :sort_order => :game_date_desc } do
end. 

I need to write something like  <br>
ActiveAdmin.register Game, { :sort_order => [:game_date_desc, :game_order_asc ] } do
end.  

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @Breenho I also wanted to set default sort order to be something more complex. I added a monkeypatch that looks something like this https://gist.github.com/ilyakatz/ad94969b400c311f2522