# Rails Active Admin how to config.sort_order with 2 columns (1 column from association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, activeadmin

In Active Admin would like to know how to setup config.sort_order with 2 columns where first column is come from same model and second column is from associated model?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Race do
  menu parent: :races, :label => proc{ I18n.t('activerecord.models.races') }
  belongs_to :meeting, :optional => true
  #need to order by "meetings.date desc races.time desc"
  config.sort_order = "?"



  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.includes(:meeting)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565219/activeadmin-sortable-by-multiple-columns

Answer (score -2):

**config.sort_order** will accept sorting by multiple fields,
the format is "**field1_(asc|desc), field2_(asc|desc)**" preserved backwards
compatibility.

Please check this link for reference. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/2432. It may resolve your problem.

Comment: That PR was never merged.